# Issue in displaying custom UIButton

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uibutton

I am trying to put a custom `UIButton` on a custom `UIView` but the `UIButton` is not appearing. Although when I try to print `UISubViews` of my `UIView`, it shows the `UIButton` object there.

Below is the piece of the code I am writing to put the button on my custom `UIView`

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        self.headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        self.headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.headerLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:kApplicationHeaderTextFont];
        [self addSubview:self.headerLabel];

        self.actionButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        self.actionButton.frame = CGRectZero;
        [self addSubview:self.actionButton];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)iTotalRect{
    if (self.actionButtonImage) {
        self.actionButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width - self.actionButtonImage.size.width - 10.0, self.frame.size.height / 2 - self.actionButtonImage.size.height / 2, self.actionButtonImage.size.width, self.actionButtonImage.size.height);
        [self.actionButton setImage:self.actionButtonImage forState:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
```

**Anybody know what I am doing wrong?**

Comment: It's an extremely bad idea to do ANYTHING inside of drawRect that you don't absolutely have to, e.g drawing. It's much much slower and will frequently have strange behaviors. That said, if you comment out your drawRect function and setup your button in your init function, will it display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I found what you need!!

maybe this:

```
 UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(aMethod:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[view addSubview:button];
```

and now u can add your options! try it!

here is something from part of my app that u can see what i mean:

```
- (void)addMyButton{    // Method for creating button, with background image and other properties

    UIButton *playButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] retain];
    playButton.frame = CGRectMake(110.0, 360.0, 100.0, 30.0);
    [playButton setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    playButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [playButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
    UIImage *buttonImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blueButton.png"];
    UIImage *strechableButtonImageNormal = [buttonImageNormal stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
    [playButton setBackgroundImage:strechableButtonImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIImage *buttonImagePressed = [UIImage imageNamed:@"whiteButton.png"];
    UIImage *strechableButtonImagePressed = [buttonImagePressed stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
    [playButton setBackgroundImage:strechableButtonImagePressed forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:playButton];  
}
```

**well I found the final solution for you:**

```
UIButton *btnTwo = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]; 
btnTwo.frame = CGRectMake(40, 140, 240, 30);
[btnTwo setTitle:@"vc2:v1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
[btnTwo setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnTwo addTarget:self action:@selector(goToOne) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:btnTwo];
```

Comment: Ok. Now when I change the button type to "UIButtonTypeRoundedRect", I can see the button appearing there but there is no image on it.

Answer (score 1):

My clue:

1.why dont u use storyboard??

2.probably it is the **alpha**?!

try to use:

```
self.alpha = 1.0;
```

Hope it worked :D

Comment: No. Alpha is ok as I can see my custom view coming fine but it does not carry button on it :-(.

Comment: posted a new solution look for!

Comment: It worked for me when I set the image as background image instead of putting it as an image. I have added the changed code in the solution here. Thanks a lot for your valuable guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a background color to your button -- it's null until you set it.

Answer (score 0):

Following piece of code in drawRect worked for me. So, basically with custom button you should not set image, you should set the background image instead.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)iTotalRect
{
    if (self.actionButtonImage) {
        self.actionButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width - self.actionButtonImage.size.width - 10.0, self.frame.size.height / 2 - self.actionButtonImage.size.height / 2, self.actionButtonImage.size.width, self.actionButtonImage.size.height);
        [self.actionButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.actionButton setBackgroundImage:self.actionButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is your initWithFrame for your actionButton?

Sorry, I was lazy to look through my code, but here is sample from the internet of how you would create custom button.

```
UIButton *playButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] retain];
playButton.frame = CGRectMake(110.0, 360.0, 100.0, 30.0);
[playButton setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
playButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[playButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
UIImage *buttonImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blueButton.png"];
UIImage *strechableButtonImageNormal = 
 [buttonImageNormal stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
[playButton setBackgroundImage:strechableButtonImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIImage *buttonImagePressed = [UIImage imageNamed:@"whiteButton.png"];
UIImage *strechableButtonImagePressed = 
[buttonImagePressed stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
[playButton addTarget:self 
action:@selector(playAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:playButton];
```

Answer (score -1):

`-initWithFrame:` may not be getting called, depending on how you are creating your button. `-initWithCoder:` is probably the being called if you’re creating your button in a .xib file.